# Extending a Eclipse vert.x application with Quarkus capabilities?

Tags: java, quarkus, vert.x

We have a large [vert.x](https://vertx.io/) application we would like to enhance with Quarkus capabilities. Currently the app starts with a classic `public static void main(String[] args)` to first collect some configuration and then kick off a `vert.x` instance to load a dozen or so Verticles.

Looking at a [Quarkus Hello World](https://quarkus.io/get-started/) example I can't see how the startup sequence happens. The first thing we are after is `quarkus dev` with its ability to hot-reload classes.

What are the steps / is there a guide to wrap an existing [vert.x](https://vertx.io/) application into quarkus?

- How to boot the app
- What to change in packaging (we don't use fatJAR)
- Adjustments needed for container build (we already use [jib](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib)
- Adjustments to log4j2 config

Pointers are appreciated

Comment: Have you read https://quarkus.io/blog/magic-control/?

Comment: can you "extend" a vert.x app into say spring boot?

Comment: Spring boot is a direct competitor to Quarkus. It relies on embedded Tomcat and below that on jetty I/O. Quarkus uses vert.x and below that netty I/O. 
On the surface you can use a lot of spring boot constructs (like the rich annotation magic) in Quarkus apps. So no you can’t mold Quarkus with boot. But you don’t need to either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:
https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_live_redeploy

What you have to do is use the Laucher class from vert.x and pass the command line arguments.

From the docs:

> To enable the live redeploy, pass the --redeploy option to the run command. The --redeploy indicates the set of file to watch. This set can use Ant-style patterns (with **, * and ?). You can specify several sets by separating them using a comma (,). Patterns are relative to the current working directory.

Basically you use a pattern in the command line to trigger the redeploy. The example there (for intelliJ) `--redeploy=**/*.class` means that every time you compile new classes (command + F9 on Mac) the application will be redeployed.

You can check the docs to see if it fits your all the points you mentioned, I believe it should work fine, but I never tested with the log files.